# node-cron by an http post request

Tags: json, node.js, cron, server

i'm using node-cron for task scheduling, in order to start the job, i have to make an http post to my server. Everything goes well until the server makes a post request by itself(auto post) for the second time, since it doesn't receive any json response. Json response returns after the cron job finishes but apparently my server is impatient. I can track the auto post which confuses cron by looking at the console outputs.

```
router.post('/SomeUrl', function(req, res, next) {

    job = new CronJob('0 44 13 * * *', function() {
     var index = 0;

      if(index <=10){
              job.stop();
      }
          else{
              console.log(req.body);
              console.log("cronJob Executed");
              index ++;
            }
        },
        function() {
            console.log("job finished");
            return res.json({
                type: true,
                data: ""
            });

        }, true, 'Europe/Istanbul');
});
```

Comment: can you please post some code. May be I can try to tweak something into it.

Comment: i added some example code for my case, thank you @Abie

Comment: I am sorry If I am deviating from the actual requirement, but I need a clarification - Your actual task is to do some processing when a particular cron job is called? If yes, why do we need to make post API, when we can create a node scheduler irrespective of post/get API.

Comment: i should be able to start cron job manually from my client side with a button click. Thats why i am using a post request to an url to make cron start. Maybe i'm missing something ? Is there a way to call cron job from the client side without sending an http post request? @Abie

Comment: I think there is some kind of confusion. You want to initiate a piece of code using cron job (as time scheduled job, which will be triggered itself after a particular interval) or you want to execute this piece of code using your API call? Or you want both together (which I think will be rare case)?

Comment: i have a piece of code that needs to be executed everyday at a specific time which is within the body of cron. But it cron job.start() must be triggered by me so cron should wait and listen for me to start the job from the client side, whenever i want. Only then, cron should execute the code. @Abie